# Is it possible to have multiple Private Key for a given Public Key?

Tags: android, certificate, public-key-encryption

Considering that the public key of the package is completely visible to every other app:

- Is it possible to generate a new private key for the given public key of a package?

Comment: If it were possible  then public key crypto wouldn't be much use......

Comment: @MitchWheat you mean, my public key, although visible, can't be used in conjunction with any other key to form a key-pair?

Comment: @MohsenAfshin Are you asking "Are there multiple strings that work as private key for a given public key, though it may be impossible to guess them?" or are you asking "Is it feasible to find the/a private key for a given public key?" ? Mitch seems to refer to the latter.

Comment: @delnan I know the possible hole, but the problem is that the one who may do this (generate new key) have malicious goals so it's may not be  his/her concern.